# Passing this.props to nested functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
handleFormSubmit(event){
        let currentComponent = this;
        const { t } = this.props;
        event.preventDefault();

        UserService.isAccount(event, this.props).then(function(status) {
            if(status === statusCode.OK) {
                 UserService.forgottenPasswordEmail(event, currentComponent.props).then(function (status){
                    toast.notify("t('forgottenPassword.emailSent')");  
                  }) 
            } else {
               toast.notify(t('forgottenPassword.emailNotSent'));
            }  
        })

}
```

As seen above, I'm trying to pass this.props to the UserService.isAccount function to the UserService.forgottenPasswordEmail function which is called inside the .then of the last one. I've tried to reference this with currentComponent but it doesn't seem to work as I get 'Cannot read property 'constructor' of null'.

How can I achieve this?

Update. This shows Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'target' of undefined.

```
handleFormSubmit(event){
    let currentComponent = this;
    const { t } = this.props;
    event.preventDefault();
    const { aux } = event;
    UserService.isAccount(aux, this.props).then(function(status) {
        if(status === statusCode.OK) {
            UserService.forgottenPasswordEmail(aux, currentComponent.props).then(function (status){
               toast.notify("t('forgottenPassword.emailSent')");  
             }) 
        } else {
           toast.notify(t('forgottenPassword.emailNotSent'));
        }  
    })     
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is event pooling in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114196/what-is-event-pooling-in-react)

Comment: I don't think the problem is `this`, even the error message doesn't say that `this` is a problem.

Comment: You can't pass the React `event` object asynchronously, but you can capture the values you need and pass these values in the async callbacks.

Comment: And to learn more about context: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1218980)

Comment: `let currentComponent = this;` is not doing what I think you think it is doing. You would need to use a ref instead. Altho it doesn't appear you even need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was adding event.persist().

```
handleFormSubmit(event){
    let currentComponent = this;
    const { t } = this.props;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
    UserService.isAccount(event, this.props).then(function(status) {
        if(status === statusCode.OK) {
            UserService.forgottenPasswordEmail(event, currentComponent.props).then(function (status){
               toast.notify(t('forgottenPassword.emailSent'));  
             }) 
        } else {
           toast.notify(t('forgottenPassword.emailNotSent'));
        }  
    })     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should accomplish what you're trying to do. One issue is you're losing the context of "this" and `let currentComponent = this;` is not doing what I think you think it is doing. You would need to use a ref instead. But it doesn't appear that you even need to do that.

```
handleFormSubmit(event){
    const { props } = this;
    const { t } = props;
    event.preventDefault();

    UserService.isAccount(event, props).then(function(status) {
        if(status === statusCode.OK) {
             UserService.forgottenPasswordEmail(event, props).then(function (status){
                toast.notify("t('forgottenPassword.emailSent')");  
              }) 
        } else {
           toast.notify(t('forgottenPassword.emailNotSent'));
        }  
    })

}
```

Comment: My functions isAccount and forgottenPasswordEmail are set to receive this.props but not "this" which in this case you named props.

Comment: They both work fine if they are not nested to each other and I just pass event and this.props to them.

Comment: props is from this: const { props } = this;

Comment: or just using arrow functions.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes - I should have said the why. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Mm I still get the same error when using your solution

Answer (score -1):

The `this` in  `UserService.isAccount(event, this.props)` would refer to the UserService object instead of the parent component of the handleFormSubmit method.

You will need to save a reference to those props in a variable and then reference said variable in the call to `UserService.isAccount,` which I believe you are already doing with `const { t } = this.props`.

So, changing method call to `UserService.isAccount(event, t)` should fix your reference error.