# e.target is null, when i'm using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
I want to change my state, the user properties, when the you change the field on the form I want it to change the proper value on user.
```

My element that I'm passing the function to, is to handle the value and fill the state in the parent component.

Ex: user type password. I want the user object to keep the same, but the user has to change.

```
state = {
      signUp: true,
      user:{
        name: '',
        password: '',
        email: '',
        userName: ''
      }
    }

handleChange = e =>{        
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      user: {
        ...prevState.user,
       [e.target.name] : e.target.value
      }
    } 

    ));
  }



 export default function SignupForm({handleSignup, handleChange}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='login-page__main__cadastro'>


            <h4>
                 Cadastre-se para ver<span className='br'><br></br></span> fotos e vídeos dos seus <span className='br'><br></br></span> amigos.
                 </h4> 

                 <form className='login-page__main__cadastro__form'>
                  <input className='form-cadastro-item' onChange={handleChange} name='email' type='email' placeholder='email'></input>
                  <input className='form-cadastro-item' onChange={handleChange} name='name' type='text' placeholder='Nome completo'></input>
                  <input className='form-cadastro-item' onChange={handleChange} name='userName' type='text' placeholder='Nome de usuário'></input>
                  <input className='form-cadastro-item' onChange={handleChange} name='password' type='password' placeholder='Senha'></input>

                 <button onClick={handleSignup} className='btn-primary'>
                 Cadastrar-se

                 </button>

                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm getting an error: e.target is null.

Comment: Can you update your code to show that where you are adding that handle change listner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is event pooling in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114196/what-is-event-pooling-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either save the value to another variable, or use `e.persist()`:

```
handleChange = e =>{    
    let myName = e.target.name;
    let myValue = e.target.value;    
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        user: {
            ...prevState.user,
            [myName] : myValue
        }
    })); 
}
```

This is because in React uses [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) for performance reasons. From the **[event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)** section of the docs:

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent` object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

Comment: I forgot to save the event target's name to a variable as well. Try it now?