# Using Hook to control form fields with an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a form to edit a use profile. The form renders data from the `user` object. I want to use React's useState Hook to hold the state of the form and I want to keep a single object to track changes to the form using an onChange function that handles the changes to the whole user object. Why is this not working?

```
function Profile() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/v1/users/me`)
      .then(res => setUser(res.data.user))
  }, [])

  const onChange = e => {
    user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setUser(user)
  }

  return (
    < div >
      <form onSubmit={null}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor={user.name}>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name"
            className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.name ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            onChange={onChange} placeholder="Fred Flintstone" value={user.name || ''}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email"
            className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            onChange={onChange} placeholder="fred.flintstone@aol.com" value={user.email || ''}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username"
            className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.username ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            onChange={onChange} placeholder="yabadabadu" value={user.username || ''}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right" onClick={() => console.log("Logout")}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}
```

Comment: `user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;` this is [mutating the current state, which is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980) in React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying the user object in-place. When you call setUser(user), the form won't re-render because the identity of the user object hasn't changed.

Where you have:

```
  const onChange = e => {
    user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setUser(user)
  }
```

what you want to have instead is something like:

```
  const onChange = useCallback((event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    setUser(oldUser => {
      return {
        ...user,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  }, [setUser]);
```

As a general rule of thumb, you usually don't want to modify state objects in-place in React.

Comment: I think `user` should be in the dependencies as well, or you could use the callback form `setUser(oldUser => ({/**/}))` instead.

Comment: OOPS. I meant to write the callback form there!

Comment: Thank you Emile!

Comment: But then, you get another problem, [event pooling in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36114196/1218980) will mess up now that the event is used asynchronously, which [Dennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60494570/1218980) got right.

Comment: `setUser` always holds the same reference, no need it in dep array (you also might have lint warning for it)

Comment: Ouch... ok. I had not noticed I was doing that (changing the user). Still, I couldn't fix it. Look, I trie this:

`const onChange = e => {
    const newUser = user; newUser[e.target.name] = e.target.value; setUser(newUser)
  }`

Comment: Nice Richard and Emilie. Thank ou a lot for your support. I got it to work with:

const onChange = e => { setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] }) }

Answer (score 1):

You should make a copy of `users` or it will not trigger a render phase as React performs a shallow comparison with the previous state.

```
const onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
  setUser(user => ({ ...user, [name]: value }));
};
```

> `setState()` will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns `false`. If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), **calling `setState()` only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders**.

- [setState API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)