# I can't change field in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### I have task:

- When user entered into the input some word, this word must be set as a value in field `searchInput`.
- When user press button Search I see in console new state `searchInput`

**Change field `searchInput`** I implement in method `upadateStateSearchInput` in file Home.js.

But I have error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

in Table.js in this line:

```
<tbody className="table-body">
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
```

## How to fix it?

### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    searchInput: ""
  });
   
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(searchInput ) {
        const res = await apiCategory('api', {method: 'GET'}, searchInput);
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: res.data,
         }));}
    fetchData(value.searchInput); 
  }, []);

const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) =>{         //THIS METHOD
    setValue({
        searchInput: event.target.value
    });
};   

  return (
    <div>
          <Search value={value.searchInput} 
                  userEnteredValue={upadateStateSearchInput} 
                  outputInConsoleNewState={() => console.log(value.searchInput)}
           />

      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} />
   </div>
  );
};
```

### Table.js:

```
export default (props) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th onClick={props.changeSortAscDesc}>ID <small>{props.sortAscDesc}</small></th>  
        <th>TITLE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="table-body">
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

### Search.js:

```
export default ({ value, userEnteredValue, outputInConsoleNewState}) => {
  return (
    <div className="search">
        <input type="text" onChange={userEnteredValue} value={value}/>
        <button onClick={() => outputInConsoleNewState(value)}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

P.S.Also i tried to change the `upadateStateSearchInput` method like this:

```
 const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) =>{
    setValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        searchInput: event.target.value
    }));
};
```

But then error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'value of null'**

In Home.js in this line:
`searchInput: event.target.value`

Comment: probably your `res.data` is undefined. try to `console.log` it to see what it is.

Comment: The solution at the end of your own question was the right way of doing this. You're only getting an error because [react event objects are pooled and reused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36114196/1218980), so you need to put the value in a local variable first: `const { value } = event.target; setValue(prev => ({ ...prev, searchInput: value }));`

Comment: And the good practice with hooks is to use multiple `useState`, one for each different state you'd like to keep track of. e.g. `const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");` and `const [listCategory, setListCategory] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change :

```
const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) =>{         //THIS METHOD
    setValue({
        searchInput: event.target.value
    });
};
```

By:

```
const upadateStateSearchInput = (valueFromInput) =>{         //THIS METHOD
    setValue({
        ...value,                       // keep your state as it is
        searchInput: valueFromInput // And just change searchInput as you did before
    });
};
```

In your Home component.
I think the value given to your method `upadateStateSearchInput` is the value entered by the input.

Comment: please explain what you did and why it didn't work in my old code. I just want to understand what the problem was past

Comment: @dok First, the value sent by the input is not a event, just a simple string, so i replaced `event` with `valueFromInput` in you method `upadateStateSearchInput `. I also added the `...value`. When you update a state, you need to keep its previous value (that is what '...value' do) and then set the property you want to change.

Comment: Here is a link about these three dots, it's a must know ;) https://dev.to/sagar/three-dots---in-javascript-26ci

Answer (score 0):

You are setting store like this.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    searchInput: ""
  });
```

Your onchange is setting `listCategory` to undefined. `.map` of `undefined` is throwing error. In order to code on safe side, please start using optional chaining.

```
const upadateStateSearchInput = (event) => {         //THIS METHOD
    setValue({
        searchInput: event.target.value
    });
};
```