# updating an array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to update an object of names in the state before passing it as a props to another component.

```
// some code above

this.state = {
    // some other states
    playerName: {
        player1Name: 'Default Player 1 Name',
        player2Name: 'Default Player 2 Name',
        player3Name: 'Default Player 3 Name'
    }
};
this.nameChange = this.nameChange.bind(this);

nameChange(e){
    this.setState( prevState => ({
        playerName: {
            ...prevState.playerName,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        }
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type='name' id='player1Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
            <input type='name' id='player2Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
            <input type='name' id='player3Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, it returns the error of unable to read 'id' of null and 'value' of null

Comment: could you please provide a link to code snippet?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @OlexandrPoplavskyi don't encourage off-site links without further qualification, they should be supplementary at most.

Comment: Read here about [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) in react. Your event has already been reset since you're using a functional update. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114196/what-is-event-pooling-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous, and react uses [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), so by the time the queued state update is processed the event has been nullified and returned back to the pool. You can either destructure the `id` and `value` properties *before* enqueueing the update.

```
nameChange(e){
  const { id, value } = e.target;
  this.setState( prevState => ({
    playerName: { ...prevState.playerName, [id]: value }
  });
}
```

Or you can flag the event to persist ([event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling))

> **Note:**
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

```
nameChange(e){
  e.persist();
  this.setState( prevState => ({
    playerName: { ...prevState.playerName, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never knew about this as many tutorials I went through always used this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value)}. Hence I thought it can be reused it this way when it comes to updating a list. Will read more about Synthetic events!

Answer (score 0):

you need use `name` in `input` and `e.target.name` in `handler`. Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";

export default class PlayerName extends React.Component {
    state = {
        // some other states
        playerName: {
            player1Name: 'Default Player 1 Name',
            player2Name: 'Default Player 2 Name',
            player3Name: 'Default Player 3 Name'
        }
    };

    nameChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;

         this.setState(prevState => ({
            playerName: {
                ...prevState.playerName,
                [name]: value
            }
        }));
        console.log( this.state);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='name' name='player1Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
                <input type='name' name='player2Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
                <input type='name' name='player3Name' onChange={this.nameChange}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```