# My react event pooling pseudo example makes sense?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, pooling

### TLDR

> Can I check about implementation about `event pooling` logic in react.
> And I want to know about `event pooling` principle :)

### Question

When I deep dive to react document, I see about `event pooling`.
So, I'm so curious about what is `event pooling` and I research about it.

And now I realize about `thread pooling`. So it is working similarly. So I make some pseudo `event pooling` logic.
And I want to know it does make sense?

> And any one who know about where `event pooling` implementation is in `react` package.
> Just comment to me please

### Pseudo event pooling

EventPool pseudo implementation

```js
class EventPool {
  private static instance: EventPool;
  private taskQueue: Event[] = [];
  private constructor() {
    this.taskQueue = [];
  }

  public static shared() {
    if (!EventPool.instance) {
      EventPool.instance = new EventPool();
    }
    return EventPool.instance;
  }

  enqueue = (event: Event) => {
    this.taskQueue = this.taskQueue.concat(event);
  };

  dequeue = (currentTarget: any) => {
    this.taskQueue = this.taskQueue.filter(
      (event: Event) => event.currentTarget === currentTarget
    );
  };

  clear() {
    // This function called before or after render 
    // (Commit -> Render -> EventPool.shared().clear()) or (Commit -> EventPool.shared().clear() -> Render) 
    this.taskQueue = this.taskQueue.filter((event) => event.isDone === true);
  }
}
```

Event pseudo implementation about `persist`

```js
class Event {
  persist = () => {
    // This is executed before EventPool.shared.clear
    EventPool.shared().dequeue(this);
  };
}
```

### Reference

1. [What is event pooling in react? - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114196/what-is-event-pooling-in-react)
2. [Synthetic Event - React Document](https://ko.reactjs.org/docs/events.html)
3. [What's the meaning of Event Pooling?](https://stackoverrun.com/ko/q/11936363)
4. [진보된 쓰레드 풀링 기법 구현 - Korean](https://javacan.tistory.com/entry/10)

Comment: [React 17 removed event pooling](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#no-event-pooling), just FYI...

Comment: Oh I see it, But I just want to know about this principle !

Comment: Thank so much Patrick Roberts!

Comment: Your `EventPool` doesn't make sense, no. The purpose was to create a pre-allocated pool of `SyntheticEvent` objects, and reuse those instances to decrease the burden on garbage collection. Your `EventPool` does not demonstrate this optimization, and in fact creating new `taskQueue` array instances with every `filter()` and `concat()` will put _more_ burden on garbage collection.

Comment: Oh I see it! I just want to know about real event pool's logic :0 It just my pseudo code! `filter()` and `concat()` is just for descript actions

Comment: But evidently in practice, React decided that the micro-optimization of event pooling didn't actually improve performance, and wasn't worth the confusion to developers dealing with asynchronicity-based bugs using these `SyntheticEvent` objects from the pool.

Comment: Oh What I understanding is that event pooling is not that optimized, so I can ignore them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is quite simple example of `SyntheticEvent`/`EventPool` pattern. Obviously in real life it'll be a bit more complex to better respect of event's behavior, but this snippet have to shed some light on concept.

```
class SyntheticEvent {
    // all the following properties and methods are part of React's
    // synthetic event, but we'll skip it here in favor of simplicity

    // bubbles: boolean
    // currentTarget: DOMEventTarget
    // defaultPrevented: boolean
    // eventPhase: number
    // nativeEvent: DOMEvent
    // preventDefault(): void {}
    // isDefaultPrevented(): boolean { return true }
    // stopPropagation(): void {}
    // isPropagationStopped(): boolean { return true }
    // target: DOMEventTarget
    // timeStamp: number
    // type: string

    // for simplicity we'll consider here only 3 following properties
    isTrusted: boolean
    cancelable: boolean
    persist: () => void

    // this property helps to track status of each synthetic event
    status: 'POOLED' | 'PERSISTED' | 'IN_USE'

    constructor(status, onPersist: () => void) {
        this.status = status;
        this.persist = onPersist;
    }
}

class EventPool {
    private pool: SyntheticEvent[] = [];

    constructor(initialPoolSize: number) {
        // populating pool with pre-allocated events. We will try to re-use
        // them as much as possible to reduce GC load
        for(let i = 0; i < initialPoolSize; i++) {
            this.allocateNewEvent();
        }
    }

    pullEvent(nativeEvent): SyntheticEvent {
        const syntheticEvent = this.getEventFromPool();
        this.populateEvent(syntheticEvent, nativeEvent);
        return syntheticEvent;
    }

    tryPushEvent(syntheticEvent: SyntheticEvent): void {
        if(syntheticEvent.status !== 'PERSISTED') {
            this.clearEvent(syntheticEvent);
        }
    }


    private allocateNewEvent(): SyntheticEvent {
        const newEvent = new SyntheticEvent( 'POOLED', () => {
            newEvent.status = 'PERSISTED';
        });
        this.pool.push(newEvent);
        return newEvent;
    }

    private getEventFromPool() {
        let event = this.pool.find( e => e.status === 'POOLED' );
        if(!event) {
            event = this.allocateNewEvent();
        }

        return event;
    }

    /** Populates synthetic event with data from native event */
    private populateEvent(syntheticEvent: SyntheticEvent, nativeEvent) {
        syntheticEvent.status = 'IN_USE';
        syntheticEvent.isTrusted = nativeEvent.isTrusted;
        syntheticEvent.cancelable = nativeEvent.cancelable;
    }

    /** Sets all previously populated synthetic event fields to null for safe re-use */
    private clearEvent(syntheticEvent: SyntheticEvent) {
        syntheticEvent.status = 'POOLED';
        syntheticEvent.isTrusted = null;
        syntheticEvent.cancelable = null;
    }
}

// Usage
const mainEventPool = new EventPool(2);
smth.onClick = nativeEvent => {
    const syntheticEvent = mainEventPool.pullEvent(nativeEvent);
    userDefinedOnClickHandler(syntheticEvent); // <-- on click handler defined by user
    mainEventPool.tryPushEvent(syntheticEvent);
};
```

> Event Pooling - React uses SyntheticEvent which is a wrapper for
> native browser events so that they have consistent properties across
> different browsers. The event handlers that we have in any react-app
> are actually passed instances of SyntheticEvent unless we use
> nativeEvent attribute to get the underlying browser event.
>
> Wrapping native event instances can cause performance issues since
> every synthetic event wrapper that's created will also need to be
> garbage collected at some point, which can be expensive in terms of
> CPU time.
>
> React deals with this problem by allocating a synthetic instance pool.
> Whenever an event is triggered, it takes an instance from the pool and
> populates its properties and reuses it. When the event handler has
> finished running, all properties will be nullified and the synthetic
> event instance is released back into the pool. Hence, increasing the
> performance.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53500357/1040070

Comment: Oh I see :) Thank you so much :)